# Optional Field Expression of Karate Framework is not working

Tags: karate

customer object either returns null or with fields as shown below with valid values. Upon going through the page https://github.com/karatelabs/karate, section Optional fields and implementing the logic as explained in JSON schema the code doesn't work

Response 1:

```
{
  "data": {
     "itemDescription": "chocolate"
     "itemAmount": 2.01
     "customer":{
          "id": "1234",
          "firstName": "ABC",
          "lastName": "XYZ"
          }
     "oId": "764328421"
     }
}
```

Response 2:

```
{
  "data": {
     "itemDescription": "chips"
     "itemAmount": 4.99
     "customer": null
     "oId": "8394821"
     }
}
```

```
Feature: <>
Scenario Outline: <>
Given
When method POST
Then status 200
* match response == read('classpath:com/<schemapath>/JSONSchema.json')
```

JSONSchema:

```
{
  "data": {
     "itemDescription": "#string"
     "itemAmount": "#number"
     "customer":"##({id:'#string',firstName:'#string',lastName:'#string'})"
     "oId": "#string"
     }
}
```

(##) means the key is either optional or null

Above code is a pass for Response 1 but fails for Response 2 with below **Error Message**
$.data.customer | data types don't match (NULL:MAP)
null
{"id":"#string","firstName":"#string","lastName":"#string"}

Answer (score 0):

There is an edge case when re-using schemas and when optional fields are involved. This is explained in the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#remove-if-null

So try this:

```
* json expected = karate.readAsString(`classpath:com/${schemapath}/JSONSchema.json`)
* match response == expected
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response. I did try and below are the results.

Now Response 1 is failing with below error message and Response 2 is working fine
Error Message
SyntaxError: Unnamed:1:32 Expected ; but found :
{id: '#string', firstName: '#string', lastName: '#string'}
                                ^

Steps modified in Feature as below 
* json expectedResponse = karate.readAsString('classpath:com/${schemapath}/JSONSchema.json')
* match response == expectedResponse

Comment: @skm then please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - also consider accepting previous answers on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers